# Two Way Data Binding But in C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, webclient, backend

Some website X manually prompts the user to enter a number which is then displayed somewhere on X to the public. Now, how do I ask the user in the C# built software in Visual Studio 2015 to do the same and then upload/update the integer value on the X without going to the X?

I have also been made to realise that something similar exists in Angular 2 with TypeScript called two-way data binding. Is there a class in C# that can implement this feature? And if I do have to go on to learn Angular, how would I merge the coding in the back-end with C# code?

Besides C# and angular, what else would I have to learn to be able to develop this feature? I know I need to be somewhat familiar with HTML and CSS.

Thank You.

Comment: *"upload/update the integer value on the X without going to the X"*. If an X manually prompts a user in the forest, what is the sound of one X clapping? If I ask for more detail, you're going to start a sentence with "basically", aren't you?

Comment: I don't really know what to say. This is just so broad. There is too much confusion for me to take responsibility for at the moment.

Comment: Consider checking out ASP.NET with the MVVM pattern.  That's about the best I can do on such a broad question